# Parse socket data on a PHP socket_listener

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I was able to open a PHP TCP listener socket, but I don't know how to parse the buffer. The client that connects to my socket send a text/html with an additional boundary data with a xml file and an image file.

How can I parse the response to get the XML file on one side and the Image on the other side?

```
server = socket_create_listen(8086);
socket_getsockname($server, $addr, $port);
if (!$server) {
    $message = 'Start TCP socket: Ko. Could not create socket.';
    $this->logger->info($message);
    die($message);
} else {
    $message = 'Start TCP socket: Ok. TCP socket opened on: ' . $addr . ':' . $port . '.';
    $this->logger->info($message);

    while ($c = socket_accept($server)) {
        socket_getpeername($c, $raddr, $rport);
        $this->logger->info("Received Connection from $raddr:$rport\n");

        $data = '';
        while ($bytes = socket_recv($c, $r_data, 1024, MSG_WAITALL)) {
            $data .= $r_data;
        }

        //Edited: Explode with double line and got data
        $parsedData = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data);
        $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($parsedData[2]);

        print_r($xml);

        else {
            echo "socket_recv() failed; reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($c)) . "\n";
        }

        socket_close($c);
    }
}
fclose($server);
```

This is the output I received:

Received Connection from :59048

```
Read 3096 bytes from socket_recv(). Closing socket...POST /test HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: zh-CN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=-------------------------7e13971310878
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 0.0.0.0:7200
Content-Length: 516032
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

---------------------------7e13971310878
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file.xml";filename="file.xml";
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 2273

<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ipAddress></ipAddress>
<ipv6Address></ipv6Address>
<portNo></portNo>
<!--REST OF XML DATA-->
</EventNotificationAlert>

---------------------------7e13971310878
Content-Disposition: form-data;name="image.jpg";filename="image.jpg";
Content-Type: image/pjpeg
Content-Length: 7164

����JFIF���



       !"$"^C
```

**EDITED: I was able to got the XML data by using "explode" function, but I don't know how to get the 2 images as image files. Any suggestion?**

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write my final solution here:

1 - Explode the data in a string to an array(using \r\n\r\n):

```
$parsedData = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data);
```

2 - XML is actually on position 2 (position 0 and 1 contain POST HTTP Header and boundary start section):

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($parsedData[2]);
```

3. Image is on position 4 (array position 3 contains headers such as Content-Disposition that must be skipped):

The code to save the data as an image is:

```
//Generate GD image from raw string.
if (!$source = @imagecreatefromstring($parsedData[4])){
    $message = 'Save Image: Ko. Img path: "' . $imgFullPath . '". Error details: ' . error_get_last()['message'];
    $this->logger->error($message);
}else {
    //Save GD image on disk
    imagejpeg($source, $imgFullPath);

    //Clean resources.
    imagedestroy($source);

    $message = 'Save Image: Ok. Image saved successfully on path: "' . $imgFullPath . '"...';
    $this->logger->info($message);
    $this->io->writeln($message);
```